# Window theme is broken

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz, window

All white is now black or transparent. Also the icons on the desktop became very large.

[image]

I'm not sure if that's the cause but I added the `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` ppa and the `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` ppa, but after that I used ppa-purge on both of them. Tried restarting.

I use `oomox` for the theme. Can it be the problem?

How do I get a stable unity desktop back?

Tried reinstalling unity `sudo apt install --reinstall unity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the theme. I have Unity Tweak Tool and I just switched the theme back and forth and things got fixed.

But apparently my Ambiance theme is broken. I use a custom theme generated by oomox so I don't mind. I also don't know how my custom theme got broken, I regenerated it and switched back to it and it's back.

For anyone else seeing this, I think you should search for how to "reinstall Ambiance theme" (this is the default theme for ubuntu).